# Log4j RollingFileAppender overwrites the old files

Tags: log4j, rollingfileappender

My appender is defined as below:

```
   <appender name="M_FILE" class="org.jboss.logging.appender.RollingFileAppender">
     <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
     <param name="File" value="${jboss.server.home.dir}/log/m_ser.log"/>
     <param name="Append" value="false" />
     <param name="MaxFileSize" value="5MB"/>
     <!--param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="25"/-->
     <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
       <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE}  %-5p [%c] %m%n"/>
     </layout>      
   </appender>

<root>
      <appender-ref ref="M_FILE"/>

   </root>
```

With this, I get m_ser.log upto 5MB, then it created m_ser.log.1, then it it created m_ser.log.2 and m_ser.log.1 file is missing. After a while, m_ser.log.3 got created and m_se.log.2 is missing.

It looks like the log4j is overwriting the backup files or it is unable to keep the old file.

This is log4j 1.2, Windows 7 system and JBoss 4.1

Answer (score 1):

The `MaxBackupIndex` parameter should define how many backup files (.1,.2,.3, etc) are kept before it starts overwriting them.